# ForgotPassword Function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, forgot-password

Can someone help me figuring out why Forgot Password isn't working?

I have this in my View:

```
 <p>
 @Html.ActionLink("Kennwort vergessen?", "ForgotPassword")
 </p>
```

This in my Controller:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            {
                // Nicht anzeigen, dass der Benutzer nicht vorhanden ist oder nicht bestätigt wurde.
                return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }
            // Weitere Informationen zum Aktivieren der Kontobestätigung und Kennwortzurücksetzung finden Sie unter "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771".
            // E-Mail-Nachricht mit diesem Link senden
            var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account",
            new { UserId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password",
            "Please reset your password by clicking here: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
            return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
        }

        // Wurde dieser Punkt erreicht, ist ein Fehler aufgetreten; Formular erneut anzeigen.
        return View(model);
    }
```

When debugging it doesn't even jump into the code where it's beeing handlet, what am I missing?